# Examples of Lewis base nature of sulfur dioxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I have read that sulfur dioxide acts as both Lewis base (due to presence of lone pair over $\ce{S}$ and/or $\ce{O})$ and Lewis acid (due to presence of vacant d orbital). I found many examples of $\ce{SO2}$ acting as a Lewis acid (towards $\ce{NMe3},$ $\ce{H2O},$ etc.), but could not find any for its Lewis base behavior. Could someone provide some reactions/equations, please?

Comment: Sulfur dioxide doesn’t use ‘vacant d orbitals’ in bonding.

Comment: See here for Lewis acid behavior: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/99928/61578

Answer (score 13):

You generally want to find a much stronger Lewis acid (typically forming a solvate/adduct) or make a complex with a transition metal: this way either unshared electron pair of oxygen or sulfur can be donated.
Canonical examples are given in *Shriver & Atkins’ Inorganic Chemistry* [1, p. 135]:

> To act as a Lewis base, the $\ce{SO2}$ molecule can donate either its $\ce{S}$ or its $\ce{O}$ lone pair to a Lewis acid. When $\ce{SbF5}$ is the acid, the $\ce{O}$ atom of $\ce{SO2}$ acts as the electron pair donor, but when $\ce{Ru(II)}$ is the acid, the $\ce{S}$ atom acts as the donor … $(\ce{[RuCl(NH3)4(SO2)]+}).$

[image: SbF5-SO2]$\qquad$[image: RuCl(NH3)4(SO2)]+]

**Figure 1**. **Left**: Crystal structure of $\ce{SbF5 · SO2}$ (ICSD-67273 [[2](https://doi.org/10.1515/znb-1989-1218)]). **Right**: Crystal structure of $\ce{[RuCl(NH3)4(SO2)]+}$ (ICSD-26061 [[3](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50030a015)]). Color code: $\color{#EEEEEE}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{H}$; $\color{#3050F8}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{N}$; $\color{#FF0D0D}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{O}$; $\color{#90E050}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{F}$; $\color{#FFFF30}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{S}$; $\color{#1FF01F}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Cl}$; $\color{#248F8F}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Ru}$; $\color{#9E63B5}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Sb}$.

Reactions for the synthetic procedures adapted from the corresponding articles [[2](https://doi.org/10.1515/znb-1989-1218), [3](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50030a015)]:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{SbF5(s) + SO2(l) &->[\pu{-40 °C}] SbF5 · SO2(sln)} \tag{R1} \\
\ce{[Ru^{II}(NH3)4(HSO3)2](aq) + 2 HCl(aq) &->[reflux][15 min] [Ru^{II}(NH3)4(SO2)Cl]Cl(aq) + 2 H2O(l) + SO2(aq)} \tag{R2}
\end{align}
$$

#### References

1. Atkins, P. W. *Shriver & Atkins’ Inorganic Chemistry*; W.H. Freeman and Co.: New York, **2010**. ISBN 978-1-4292-1820-7.
2. Minkwitz, R.; Molsbeck, W.; Preut, H. Kristallstruktur von $\ce{SbF5 · SO2}$ / Crystal Structure of $\ce{SbF5 · SO2}.$ *Zeitschrift für Naturforschung B* **1989**, 44 (12), 1581–1583. DOI: [10.1515/znb-1989-1218](https://doi.org/10.1515/znb-1989-1218). (Free Access)
3. Vogt, L. H.; Katz, J. L.; Wiberley, S. E. The Crystal and Molecular Structure of Ruthenium-Sulfur Dioxide Coordination Compounds. I. Chlorotetraammine(Sulfur Dioxide)Ruthenium(II) Chloride. *Inorg. Chem.* **1965**, 4 (8), 1157–1163. DOI: [10.1021/ic50030a015](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50030a015).